# Where is logout.qml location for KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, plasma5

I want to add Hibernate Button and change background color of shutdown menu.

I know these settings are in `logout.qml`, so I went to `~/.local` folder and searched for plasma look and feel as suggested by some posts but there was no `logout.qml` in that folder. Also I tried a made-up solution: i did `tree -f | grep logout.qml` but even in this way I did not find that file.

Where is `logout.qml` location for KDE Plasma 5?

Comment: I went to ~/.local folder and searched for plasma look and feel as suggested by some posts but there was no logout.qml in that folder. Also i tried a made up solution , i did `tree -f | grep logout.qml` but even in this way i did not find that file.

Comment: `locate -i logout.qml`? I get `/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/logout/Logout.qml`

Comment: Yes perfect. I am a novice linux user and i didn't know about locate program.